# Initializing Redis values as part of a docker-compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a **docker-compose** setup containing multiple services, and among them I have a redis service.

I use it for both my continuous integration flow, and manual local-runs of the system. I would like to be able to set initial content to that redis for these non-production flows.

I considered setting [an entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) in my docker-compose file and adding my script, but I wouldn't want to override the default entrypoint. How may I concatenate my script to it instead?

The actual script I require would probably include just 4 commands:

- Open redis cli
- Log into the specific redis instance
- Set required values
- Perhaps disconnect from the redis instance?

Is there a cleaner solution than overriding the entrypoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's part of your continuous integration flow, then why not add an extra step to your flow that runs this script against the redis container after you boot the docker-compose environment?

That would be the proper place for this logic, as your containers probably shouldn't be responsible for populating their own state, this should be the task of your surrounding build/deploy scripting.

---

For manual local runs, your best bet is still to script this 'outside' your container: move from using `docker-compose up` for your local runs to a custom `up.sh` script that sets up this state for you each time you run it (perhaps passing any script arguments through to the `docker-compose` commands inside).

Comment: That's a good argument for the CI, but I forgot to mention that I also use these images for manual local-runs, where optimally just docker-compose up would be run. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly!